# Animation not playing after dismissViewController iOS

Tags: ios, animation, dismiss

I have an "`AViewController`" is root `viewController` and I have an image is playing animation infinite loop.

```
- (void)rotateImageView
{ 
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        [self.imageViewSpin setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(self.imageViewSpin.transform, M_PI_2)];
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if (finished) {
            [self rotateImageView];
        }
    }];
}
```

in viewWillAppear

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(rotateImageView) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
    [self rotateImageView];
}
```

This work great if my application become to active. But when I'm  try to presentViewController "`CViewController`"
`[self.navigationController presentViewController: animated: completion:]`
And I have Back button on "`CViewController`"

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"checkIsPresent" object:self];
    }];
```

After returning to "`AviewController`",animation stops working.
How to solve this issue.
Thank you.

**Edit.**

Work now I just put `[self rotateImage];` in method from postNotification.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(rotateImageView) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkPresentView) name:@"checkIsPresent" object:nil];
    [self rotateImageView];
}
-(void)checkPresentView{
    //isModalView = false;
    [self rotateImageView];
}
```

Comment: You do not need to add an observer and post notification from CViewController. The [self rotateImageView] method itself will be called as AViewController's `viewWillAppear` will get called when dismissing CViewController

Comment: Oh, That post notification I'm use for another thing, sorry for that I'll edit it.So from viewWillAppear it's work but my animation not loop just run only 1/4 of a circle and animation will stop.

Comment: You could try calling [view.layer removeAllAnimations]; in viewWillDisappear

Comment: Thank for suggestion I'll merge it with my working code.

Comment: Great that you have made it work, post your edit as the answer